# Trying to understand function application operator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, operators

I'm trying to wrap my head around the function application operator (`$`) in Haskell.

I'm working through the examples in Learn You a Haskell, and I thought I understood the following example:

```
Prelude> map ($ 3) [(+4), (*10), (^2), sqrt]
[7.0,30.0,9.0,1.7320508075688772]
```

I then tried the following variant, which also worked fine:

```
Prelude> map ($ 3) [(+4), (*10), (\x -> x^2), sqrt]
[7.0,30.0,9.0,1.7320508075688772]
```

Finally, I tried modifying the third function in the list as follows, which generates an error:

```
Prelude> map ($ 3) [(+4), (*10), (\x -> 2^x), sqrt] 
<interactive>:53:38:
    Ambiguous type variable `b0' in the constraints:
      (Floating b0)
        arising from a use of `sqrt' at <interactive>:53:38-41
      (Integral b0) arising from a use of `^' at <interactive>:53:33
      (Num b0) arising from the literal `3' at <interactive>:53:8
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the expression: sqrt
    In the second argument of `map', namely
      `[(+ 4), (* 10), (\ x -> 2 ^ x), sqrt]'
    In the expression: map ($ 3) [(+ 4), (* 10), (\ x -> 2 ^ x), sqrt]
Prelude>
```

It seems if the final `sqrt` function is somehow begin associated with the previous list element, as the following variant works ok:

```
Prelude> map ($ 3) [(+4), (*10), (\x -> 2^x)]
[7,30,8]
```

Can someone enlighten me as to what's going on here?

Comment: one lesson to take from this, after trying something out at GHCi prompt, check its *type*, with **`Prelude> :t it`**. "It" is a special word, referring to the previous result, and `:t` asks to see a type. You could see that there are no decimal points in the numbers in your last example. Also, after entering **`:s +t`** at the prompt, the GHCi will report the type for every result it produces.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The type of the used exponentiation operator is

```
(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
```

so when you use `\x -> 2^x`, you get an `Integral` constraint for the `3`. But `sqrt` imposes a `Floating` constraint. So the type of the 3 must satisfy

```
3 :: (Integral t, Floating t) => t
```

but there is no instance for both among the default type list, which is `Integer` and `Double`, so the defaulting fails, and you're left with an ambiguous type variable.

When you had `\x -> x^2`, there was only a `Num` constraint from the first functions, and `Floating` from `sqrt`, so the type was defaulted to `Double`.

You can make it work if you use

```
(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
```

as your exponentiation operator, then the type can again be defaulted to `Double`.

Comment: Then he could fix it, replacing (^) by (**).

Comment: Thanks both Daniel and Zurgl -- that clarifies things considerably. Coming from Python I'm still wrapping my head around the implications of strict type checking.